# PHP download script corrupts the file

Tags: php, download

what could be a problem of that, file int the server is good, but after I press download it get corrupted...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ataskaita.docx"');
    readfile('../generavimui/ataskaita.docx'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't send garbage before the file output (an UTF-8 BOM will break at, as will intentional `<html>` output before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ereasing the output buffer before reading the file

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ataskaita.docx"');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile('../generavimui/ataskaita.docx'); 
}
```

Comment: it didint helped.. file is still corupted, but at this time word can repair it and there is no entries from mysql database. only plane text: name:  , adress:  ...

Comment: So if it helped there is something wrong with the headers.
try adding additional info like: header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

Comment: it still didint helped :/ I have no idea whats wrong with it.. Maybe  I should put download code into different file?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the file using notepad or a hex editor. There probably is a PHP error message in there.

Possible reasons include

- The file you are looking for doesn't exist
- `$_POST['submit']` is not set

Comment: strange thing, but in the corrupted file is page code <div> and other stuff... the file is in the server and it opens correctly from there...

Comment: @Deividas that smells of a 404, or the web provider injecting HTML code into the download

Comment: @toon81 no, before this is long code that puts required info to docx file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you are having, except I had some additional problems, such as trailing source code being included in the downloaded file.

To fix it, replace your code with this:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ataskaita.docx"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Expires: 0'); 
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

[Source Site](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3992406.htm)

Hope this helps